# .htaccess redirrect to mobile site for multiple domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Dev, Staging and Prod site using Dev.examtest.com  staging.example.com and example.com. I am trying to create a redirect using .htaccess that will work for all 3. I am using GIT to keep all 3 environments in sync and because of that I need something that will apply to all 3. Below is what I have for Prod. In each environment I edit the last line for it to work. Is there a way to have 1 set of code that will work with all 3?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !is_splash_visited=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/mobile/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `example.com` to use `%{HTTP_HOST}`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !is_splash_visited=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/mobile/$1 [R,L]
```